# pg_dump does not honor -n

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump

I'm using pg_dump (9.2 database), to extract one schema and load this into another database (9.4).

well, here's the command:

> pg_dump -f file.sql -F plain --inserts -n schema database

Ok. My command finished up really nice, but, it's not dumping everything to a schema called schema (in the example above). It's loading everything into public.

**EDIT**:

To make the question clearer:

The dump works fine. Upon inspection, it's dumping my `schema.table`, for example, to `public.table`. I want that to restored to schema, *not* public.

Any tips on solving this?

Thanks

Comment: What permissions does the user, that you create the dump with, have on the schema?

Comment: I suspect you've misunderstood what `-n` does. It should be restricting the dump to only objects in the schema `schema`, so objects in `public` and other schemas are not dumped.

Comment: @CraigRinger: It does just that. It restricted the dump to schema. What I maybe could not explain, is that I expect the schema to restored in it's original place. Everything is just going to public, instead.

Answer (score 5):

When dumping a schema with the mentioned command, as postgres user:

```sh
pg_dump -f file.sql -F plain --inserts -n schemaname database
```

it produces a file whose basic structure looks like:

```
-- various SET commands
CREATE SCHEMA schemaname;

ALTER SCHEMA schemaname OWNER TO ownername;

SET search_path = schemaname, pg_catalog;

CREATE TABLE tablename(...) ...

ALTER TABLE schemaname.tablename OWNER TO ownername;

COPY tablename (columns...) FROM stdin;
data...
\.
```

The fact that `search_path` is set to the newly created schema implies that the `CREATE TABLE` and `COPY` statements that follow will happen in that schema and not in the `public` schema.

Or `SET search_path` would have to fail, which shouldn't happen even if the creation of the schema just above in the script failed. If `schemaname` does not exist, the next schema tried would be `pg_catalog` and `CREATE TABLE` would refuse to write into it, and after that there's no next schema in the search path, and in particular not `public`.

It's hard to imagine what mishappening could cause the above script to end up creating and populating anything in the `public` schema.

Comment: In non-`-n` contexts (e.g., `-t` - single-table), the `SET search_path = schemaname, pg_catalog;` is something I really cannot fathom. It basically guarantees that if the schema doesn't exist in the target DB, all the table creation logic will fail, so why not just test for the existence of the schema in the target DB, and fail (or create schema) if it doesn't exist? Sometimes folks **want** to replicate a table to a different schema - in my work I reckon it's 75% of the use-cases, and it's a pain having to FART-edit the schema-stuff (it's the only thing I use FART for instead of awk/grep).