# Copying a PostgreSQL schema and its data from one database to another

Tags: postgresql, python, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am trying to copy a PostgreSQL schema and it's data from one database to another without impacting the availability of the current schema (`old_schema`). I would also like to do this for a specific subset of tables within the schema, and want the new schema to have a different name in the other database.

I am using Python for steps 1. and 2. in the following procedure,

1. Get a list of table names from `old_schema` that I want to copy.

```sql
    select
        distinct
        information_schema.columns.table_name as table_name
    from
        information_schema.columns
    where
        information_schema.columns.table_schema = 'public'
        and
        information_schema.columns.table_name ~ 'lime_.*'
    ;
```

2. Loop through the table names, creating the same tables in the `new_schema`

```sql
    create table if not exists {new_schema}.{lime_table} (like {old_schema}.{lime_table} including all);
```

and also copy the data over from the `old_schema` to the `new_schema` for each table

```sql
    insert into {new_schema}.{lime_table} (select * from {old_schema}.{lime_table});
```

3. Now we have a copy of the tables we want in `new_schema`.

Here comes the part with unexpected behavior from PostgreSQL. For migrating the `new_schema` to the other database, we first dump it to a file using

```
    pg_dump.exe
        --host="<HOST>"
        --port=<PORT>
        --username=<USERNAME>
        --table="lime*"  // redundant because of step 1.
        --format=c
        --schema=new_schema // our `new_schema`
        --exclude-schema="public" // doesn't work, public still being written in dump file
      "<DB_NAME>" > C:\Users\<PATH>\backup.sql
```

However, even after copying tables from `public` to `new_schema` in step 2., specifying to pg_dump to only dump `new_schema`, and also specifying to exclude the `public` schema (the schema where the data originates from), we still get `public.<table>` in the dump file! It's just like what's outlined in this question - [pg_dump does not honor -n](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/100599/245178).

4. If the dump were to work, the plan is to use the following to copy `new_schema` to a different database.

```
    pg_restore.exe
        --host="<HOST>"
        --port=<PORT>
        --username=<USERNAME>
        --verbose -1
        --dbname="<DB_NAME>"  
      C:\Users\<PATH>\backup.sql
```

The versions of PostgreSQL I am using are outlined in the dump files.

-- Dumped from database version 10.9.17

-- Dumped by pg_dump version 14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one were to refer to the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-pgdump.html), one would discover that

> The `-n` and `-N` switches have no effect when `-t` is used, because tables selected by `-t` will be dumped regardless of those switches

This seems to be exactly what is happening in your case. Contrary to what your comment says (`--table="lime*"  // redundant because`), that switch actually overrides your schema specification. You should omit `--table`.